# draw a cube at specific co-ordinates?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm looking to draw a cube at specific co-ordinates. I've got all 4 corners and the centers x/y value. I now want to construct a cube at those co-ordinates. Does anyone know of any tutorials or have any information on how I would go about said task?

Ive got the following code. I'd like to map each of its corners to a specific x/y co-ord

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;

 class GLCube {
    private final IntBuffer mVertexBuffer;


  private final IntBuffer mTextureBuffer;


   public GLCube() {

  int one = 65536;
  int half = one / 2;
  int vertices[] = {
        // FRONT
        -half, -half, half, half, -half, half,
        -half, half, half, half, half, half,
        // BACK
        -half, -half, -half, -half, half, -half,
        half, -half, -half, half, half, -half,
        // LEFT
        -half, -half, half, -half, half, half,
        -half, -half, -half, -half, half, -half,
        // RIGHT
        half, -half, -half, half, half, -half,
        half, -half, half, half, half, half,
        // TOP
        -half, half, half, half, half, half,
        -half, half, -half, half, half, -half,
        // BOTTOM
        -half, -half, half, -half, -half, -half,
        half, -half, half, half, -half, -half, };



  int texCoords[] = {
        // FRONT
        0, one, one, one, 0, 0, one, 0,
        // BACK
        one, one, one, 0, 0, one, 0, 0,
        // LEFT
        one, one, one, 0, 0, one, 0, 0,
        // RIGHT
        one, one, one, 0, 0, one, 0, 0,
        // TOP
        one, 0, 0, 0, one, one, 0, one,
        // BOTTOM
        0, 0, 0, one, one, 0, one, one, };



  // Buffers to be passed to gl*Pointer() functions must be
  // direct, i.e., they must be placed on the native heap
  // where the garbage collector cannot move them.
  //
  // Buffers with multi-byte data types (e.g., short, int,
  // float) must have their byte order set to native order
  ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
  vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
  mVertexBuffer = vbb.asIntBuffer();
  mVertexBuffer.put(vertices);
  mVertexBuffer.position(0);



  // ...
  ByteBuffer tbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texCoords.length * 4);
  tbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
  mTextureBuffer = tbb.asIntBuffer();
  mTextureBuffer.put(texCoords);
  mTextureBuffer.position(0);

 }


 public void draw(GL10 gl) {
  gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FIXED, 0, mVertexBuffer);


  gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D); // workaround bug 3623
  gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FIXED, 0, mTextureBuffer);



  gl.glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  gl.glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
  gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
  gl.glNormal3f(0, 0, -1);
  gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, 4);

  gl.glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  gl.glNormal3f(-1, 0, 0);
  gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 8, 4);
  gl.glNormal3f(1, 0, 0);
  gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 12, 4);

  gl.glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
  gl.glNormal3f(0, 1, 0);
  gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 16, 4);
  gl.glNormal3f(0, -1, 0);
  gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 20, 4);
 }


  static void loadTexture(GL10 gl, Context context, int resource) {
  Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
        context.getResources(), resource);
  GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);
  gl.glTexParameterx(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
  gl.glTexParameterx(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
  bmp.recycle();
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want to translate your cube to x y coordinate use

```
gl.glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
```

before drawing it.

[this](http://blog.jayway.com/2010/01/01/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-%E2%80%93-part-iii-%E2%80%93-transformations/) is a tutorial for opengl transformations in android.

Answer (score 0):

```
package projectLab;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.media.opengl.GL;
import javax.media.opengl.GL2;
import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import javax.media.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLJPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Cube extends GLJPanel implements GLEventListener, KeyListener {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Cube");
        GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(null);
        Cube panel = new Cube(caps);
        window.setContentPane(panel);
        window.pack();
        window.setLocation(50, 50);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);
        panel.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    private float rotateX, rotateY, rotateZ;

    public Cube(GLCapabilities capabilities) {
        super(capabilities);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        addGLEventListener(this);
        addKeyListener(this);
        rotateX = 15;
        rotateY = 15;
        rotateZ = 0;
    }

    private void cube(GL2 gl) {
        gl.glBegin(gl.GL_POLYGON);

        gl.glColor3d(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        gl.glVertex3d(0.5, -0.5, -0.5);
        gl.glVertex3d(0.5, 0.5, -0.5);
        gl.glVertex3d(-0.5, 0.5, -0.5);
        gl.glVertex3d(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5);
        gl.glEnd();

        gl.glBegin(gl.GL_POLYGON);
        gl.glColor3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        gl.glVertex3d(0.5, -0.5, 0.5);
        gl.glVertex3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
        gl.glVertex3d(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
        gl.glVertex3d(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5);
        gl.glEnd();

        gl.glBegin(gl.GL_POLYGON);
        gl.glColor3d(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        gl.glVertex3d(0.5, -0.5, -0.5);
        gl.glVertex3d(0.5, 0.5, -0.5);
        gl.glVertex3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
        gl.glVertex3d(0.5, -0.5, 0.5);
        gl.glEnd();

        gl.glBegin(gl.GL_POLYGON);
        gl.glColor3d(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        gl.glVertex3d(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5);
        gl.glVertex3d(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
        gl.glVertex3d(-0.5, 0.5, -0.5);
        gl.glVertex3d(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5);
        gl.glEnd();

        gl.glBegin(gl.GL_POLYGON);
        gl.glColor3d(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        gl.glVertex3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
        gl.glVertex3d(0.5, 0.5, -0.5);
        gl.glVertex3d(-0.5, 0.5, -0.5);
        gl.glVertex3d(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
        gl.glEnd();

        gl.glBegin(gl.GL_POLYGON);
        gl.glColor3d(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        gl.glVertex3d(0.5, -0.5, -0.5);
        gl.glVertex3d(0.5, -0.5, 0.5);
        gl.glVertex3d(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5);
        gl.glVertex3d(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5);
        gl.glEnd();

        gl.glFlush();
    }

    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {

        GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);

        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glRotatef(rotateZ, 0, 0, 1);
        gl.glRotatef(rotateY, 0, 1, 0);
        gl.glRotatef(rotateX, 1, 0, 0);

        cube(gl);

    }

    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        // called when the panel is created
        GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width,
            int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            rotateY -= 15;
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
            rotateY += 15;
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
            rotateX += 15;
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
            rotateX -= 15;
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_UP)
            rotateZ += 15;
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN)
            rotateZ -= 15;
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_HOME)
            rotateX = rotateY = rotateZ = 0;
        repaint();

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}
```

I draw it like this one.